# Podcasts app "disappearing" from background?

Tags: music, podcasts, podcasts.app, music.app

I'm trying to give the new podcasts app by Apple a go.
Every morning I listen to a podcast and then pause it when I get to work. When I want to keep listening a few hours later and just press on play again in my earphones, I see that the podcasts app is no longer the active playing app and I have to open it again. This used to work easily in the regular Music app, but with Podcasts it's like the fact that it's the last-played app gets lost after sometime.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is just how it is. After an undefined period the podcasts app is being closed by iOS to save battery and memory. If you want you can delete the Apple podcasts app and sync podcasts from iTunes. You will find the podcasts section re-appears in the music app.